# What is the difference between NSFont and UIFont

Tags: ios, uifont, nsfont

While searching the solution of a problem I found the **NSFont** and **UIFont** both,

whats the basic difference between both and when should we use?

Comment: UIFont: UIKit (iOS), NSFont (AppKit): For macOS.

Answer (score 5):

[`NSFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont) is part of [`AppKit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit) which is the UI library for MacOS.

[`UIFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont) is part of [`UIKit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit) which is the UI library for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple documentation for appkit uikit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont)

[Apple documentation for nsfont](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont)

It is pretty clear that they both are part of different framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macOS the use `NSFont`

and for iOS you will use `UiFont`